# Delphi Generics TDictionary causes [DCC Fatal Error] F2084 Internal Error: L1737 message

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-2010

I just discovered generics (astonishing I know!) and immediately fell in love with it...until I found out that Delphi 2010 (update 4 & 5 installed) fail with the dreaded `[DCC Fatal Error] F2084 Internal Error: L1737` message if I have this code:

```
// Global array of list
IDsList : Array [1..5] Of TDictionary<Int64, Int64>;

function MyProc;
var
   i : Integer;
   Enum : TDictionary<Int64, Int64>.TPairEnumerator;
begin
     // ...
     Enum := IDsList[i].GetEnumerator;
     while Enum.MoveNext do
     begin
          // ...
     end;
end;
```

Precisely, Delphi fails to compile unless I comment this line `Enum := IDsList[i].GetEnumerator;`

Using an array greatly simplify my code, is there a way to avoid this L1737 error message?

PS. I'm not new to Delphi, only generics!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That code compiles on my Delphi 2010, once the error in the declaration of `MyProc` is fixed. There's probably something else in the real code that leads to the internal error.

In any case it makes more sense to use a `for/in` loop here:

```
var
  Pair: TPair<Int64, Int64>;
....
for Pair in IDsList[i] do
  DoSomething(Pair);
```

And perhaps if you did that you'd escape the internal error.

If switching to `for/in` doesn't sidestep the internal error then you need to supply a complete program that exhibits the fault. Try and cut it down to the smallest size possible. This is always good practice when asking question, submitting bug reports etc.

In my experience, if you want to do any serious generics programming, without drowning in a flood of internal errors, you need to move beyond Delphi 2010.

Comment: I'm afraid your code didn't fix this either on my real-world project. I did track the problem down to that line, I'm certain, so it must be something else caused in my project. I do own XE2, but never really bothered upgrading this project in particular, I'll try to upgrade it, I'll post my finding later, thanks!

Comment: Small Update: I put the `Enum` declaration under the implementation section as [suggested here](https://forums.codegear.com/message.jspa?messageID=171141), ie. `implementation...

var
   Enum : TDictionary<Int64, Int64>.TPairEnumerator;` and now it compiles. However, I tend to agree that Delphi 2010 and generics don't play along very well

Comment: OK, but you can't realistically use a global variable for this.

Comment: It's almost midnight here and I feel this will be a dump question: Why not?

Comment: You said: `you can't realistically use a global variable for this.` why is that?

Comment: Because global variables are evil. Use global variables and you will burn in hell!! Seriously, this is a loop variable. It has local scope. It is only meaningful for the duration of the loop. So bind its scope as tightly as possible to the loop. Which makes it local.

Comment: Ahh OK! (and I **absolutely** agree) It's really just a temporary workaround until I migrate to XE2, hopefully this won't be painful!